# Property 'id' does not exist on type of function argument

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote a dispatch that authorizes a user, this dispatch return one of type: User or ResponseError

My dispatch

```
async loginUser ({ commit }, data) {
    try {
      const user = await loginUser(data)
      commit('setUser', user)
      return user
    } catch (e) {
      return {
        status: e.response.status,
        errors: e.response.data.errors
      }
    }
  }
```

Types

```
export interface User {
  id?: number
}

export interface ErrorResponse {
  status: number
  errors: object
}

export interface Actions {
  loginUser({ commit }: { commit: Commit }, data: LoginData): Promise<User | ErrorResponse>
}
```

And I call this action in my component like:

```
const res = await this.$store.dispatch('loginUser', {
   email: this.formData.email,
   password: this.formData.password
})

redirect(res, 'dashboard')
```

After request I try to check what return in request (in redirect function): Error or User

```
const redirect = (res: User | ErrorResponse, redirectTo: string) => {
  if (res.id) {
    router.push({ name: redirectTo })
  } else {
    ElMessage.error('Oops, this is a error message.')
  }
}
```

But TS show me an error
 `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'User | ErrorResponse'.Property 'id' does not exist on type 'ErrorResponse'.`

I understand why TS show me this error but I don't understand how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `res` can be either the `User` interface or the `ErrorResponse` interface, and TypeScript needs a hint to disambiguate. There are a few ways to resolve this.

### Use type assertion

A quick fix is to use [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) with the `as` keyword:

```js
const redirect = (res: User | ErrorResponse, redirectTo: string) => {
  if ((res as User).id) {
    // res is User or ErrorResponse
    console.log('User ID', (res as User).id)

  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyywAJgPwBcyIArgLYBG0BAvgQaJLIigKJRQA9lABKEdAAdBITDgJF0YOGBroqtRs0LJoQqGuSCGAKwgIwrdvgTTFyKBBLAH55AF5kACgcGMWAD7I-HpikrYQADT2js5mYAAqglSKUKAA5gCU7gB8ctrAMF7e4shw6GiYUBkAdKRZeNpENjKCADYQ1a2CaZ4A5H5QyACSACK9UcXlZRXQNXVWRCw6rbINREQA9BvVO-LIbPgHBA5OLmCe2MQkVACMd-tRvRuq0L0ZxzFnF8iKyqpUACYorphAZsEsWI8NiCoG8Pqc4t9SFQAMxoqK-FQGFHAgSgqjgh7IJ4wt5AA)

A disadvantage of this approach is that the type of `res` is still ambiguous within the `if`-block, so type assertion is still needed there (or a temporary variable of type `User` that refers to `res`) to access a `User`-specific property.

Instead, we can use [type narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) for added type safety, as shown below. *Note: While `typeof` or `instanceof` type guards are ways to narrow types, they cannot be used with interfaces or type aliases.*

### Use an `in` type guard

Use the [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) to check for a mutually exclusive property in one of the types, thereby narrowing to the type that passes the check. For instance, `id` is unique to `User`, so check that the property is `in` the `res` object:

```js
const redirect = (res: User | ErrorResponse, redirectTo: string) => {
  if ('id' in res && res.id) {
    // res is User
    console.log('User ID', res.id)

  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyywAJgPwBcyIArgLYBG0BAvgQaJLIigKJRQA9lABKEdAAdBITDgJF0YOGBroqtRs0LJoQqGuSCGAKwgIwrdvgTTFyKBBLAH55AF5kACgcGMWAD7I-HpikrYQADT2js5mYAAqglSKUKAA5gCU7gB8ctrAMF4A5KRFxCDR6MgAZNWVAHSkWXjaRDYyggA2EPWdgmmeRX5QyACSACJFUT6NJBlWRCw6nbIFxbrC6GWglTV1Mxv6zfJEyO3oXT2Hg8GbUw2H6PP4J0sQKygtp8gA9D9BnQAsuJ0HA0lcBMJBgB5QQSdBRMAAC2AVVRyDgOkhIzoILBPSKz0Wlhe+AcThcYE82GIJCoAEZGcgWFEij9VNBCQRybFzNTkIplKoqAAmKKPKjYJYs5Bsw5cskxSn80hUADMGqigpUBjV4uxBilzNZP3lGSAA)

### Use a type guard function with a type predicate

Use a function with a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to verify the given object is a specific type. Since `id` is unique to `User`, the function simply needs to check that the property is not `undefined`:

```js
const isUser = (obj: any): obj is User => (obj as User).id !== undefined

const redirect = (res: User | ErrorResponse, redirectTo: string) => {
  if (isUser(res)) {
    // res is User
    console.log('User ID', res.id)

  } else {
    //...
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdrIN4FgBQyywAJgPwBcyIArgLYBG0BAvgQaJLIigKJRQA9lABKEdAAdBITDgJF0YOGBroqtRs0LJoQqGuSCGAKwgIwrdvgTTFxdBiwBeZAAojxqnBABPAJRUHvZomFDITgB8bkFw6CHQfgB0pMgAhE4uNCAkEDCgECRWNjJgyFAFwOXm4W7lBo5hAD7I-HpikrYQADRlFVVgACqCVIpQoADmfuFReNrAMG7ADqGudX5Ts0RExeiCADYQiXuC464A5A3IAJIAImc9dckkflZELDp7sptbAPQ-LXsALLidBwcaHXTCc4AeUEEnQPTAAAslsE4DoBMJkHQQWDDmcXto2PhiQRyiRKmYwK5sMQSFQAIxM5AsHpnH6qaAEsl9Kk05CKZSqKgAJh6kP0VGw71ZyHZEu5+HJlPM-NIVAAzFqeoKVAYNeLMZKcDK2T8FX4gA)

Comment: Thank's! It's very good answer.

Comment: Very good answer indeed. I'm still baffled tho why simple `if(res.id)` is not enough to narrow the type to `User` interface...